# Panel regression: what is the contribution of the fixed effects to the R-squared

Tags: stata, panel-data

The following question is a general question, independent of the type of data used (although I can provide a data example if this is desired).

---

If you run a panel regression model (`xtreg` or `areg` in Stata or `plm` package in R), **is it possible to see how much "the panel structure**" (i.e. the fixed individual effects or the fixed yearly effects) **explains of the total variance in the regression** (which is for instance measured by *F* or adjusted *R*-squared)?

The reason why I wonder this is that, if I use an OLS regression on one specific year, I get *R*-square values of around 0.1. When using the panel regression, *R*-square is significantly higher (namely 0.8).

This is logic, but I would like to know now **if the variables that I included in the regression, explain a significant amount of this high *R*-square** (or whether the higher *R*-square is only/mostly explained by unobserved variables that are trapped by the fixed effects). And if so, what part of the *R*-square (for instance 50%?).

Is there a way to test this and how so? For panel data I work with Stata although I also have experience with R.

Comment: Judith Singer's paper on FE, RE, mixed, hierarchical, multilevel (it's a terminological mess) models using SAS addresses your question. Ignore the fact that it leverages SAS software, it's just an excellent introduction to mixed and/or panel models, including approaches to variance decomposition.  https://www.ida.liu.se/~732G34/info/singer.pdf